# Is there a term for words like 'frenemy'?

Tags: compound-words

I read the word 'frenemy' for the first time in a [BBC news item](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-51074956) which described the current relationship of President Trump and Kim Jong-Un as 'frenemies'.

> A person with whom one is friendly, despite a fundamental dislike or rivalry; a person who combines the characteristics of a friend and an enemy.

[Oxford English Dictionary - (requires subscription or library card)](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/273014?redirectedFrom=frenemy#eid)

Is there a term for the joining of opposites into one word like this and are there any other examples of this ?

The entry in OED (which also gives the alternate spelling 'frienemy') is sparse for references, listing only one usage :

> 1953   W. Winchell in Nevada State Jrnl. 19 May 4/4   Howz about calling the Russians our Frienemies?
>
> 1977   J. Mitford in N.Y. Times 13 Sept. 31/1   My sister and the Frenemy played together constantly,..all the time disliking each other heartily.
>
> 2001   Daily Tel. (Nexis) 22 Mar. 69   The new rules require working with competitors or ‘frenemies’ to survive.
>
> 2007   M. L. Jacobs How to Jump from Ferris Wheel & Land on your Feet 57   I cannot continue to allow myself to be stifled by the pressures of life and the people around me and this is in respect to work, lovers, associates, friends, enemies and worst of all frienemies.

Comment: It's a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau#Examples_in_English), and yes, there's tons of those, but I am not aware of dedicated term for a portmanteau that's created specifically from antonyms.

Comment: It's an *oxymoron*. Usually applied to two words such as *friend-enemy* but I see no reason not to regard their fusion as an oxymoron too.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - I agree that Donald and Kim are morons, but they bear no resemblance to oxen.  (Well, maybe they do!)